# why does the texture that says "mute" looks like that?

Tags: texturing

Why does the texture that says mute looks pink? its a text made with photoshop, exported as a png.
below the material where i am proyecting this texture, there is a cube with an emission shader on.

so how can i make the material look a little translucid, and that the texture does not changes the color?
[image]

Comment: What is it supposed to look like?

Comment: the mute text should look black, it is black in the picture i exported

Comment: Can you plug the color straight into the Principled BSDF?  Or why are you using the alpha channel?

Comment: Related: [how do I emit light from inside an object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24886/how-do-i-emit-light-from-inside-a-object) and [Button emitting light in eevee](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/174888/button-emitting-light-in-eevee?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [Applying a realistic texture over an emission object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183218/what-is-the-process-for-applying-a-realistic-texture-over-an-emission-object-ex/183228#183228)

Comment: im using because its a png and i want it to be over the color material